# Can we solve the equation for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{z}{y}$=
$(1-\frac{xa}{m_1})$
$(1-\frac{xb}{m_2})$
$(1-x)^{n-2}$

Can we solve this equation for x such that, in the new equation we have, $x$ is the dependent variable, and $n$ is the independent variable, ${n∈Z^+}$ and ${n≥2}$, "$a$", "$b$", "$m_1$", "$m_2$", "$y$", "$z$" are all constants, here "$m_1$" and "$m_2$" are both equal to 12, plz do use 12 in place of "$m_1$" and "$m_2$" if it makes it easy. I have found it impossible to isolate $x$ on one side, I hope someone can help. At the end what we prefrebly need is an equation for $x$ which contains all $a,b,m_1,m_2,y$ and $z$, I'm a computer science student and I need to solve this for making a formula

Comment: I don't think thar there exist a closed formula. Thus you have to apply an approximation method for a specific value of n.

Comment: After trying a few things, alas that $z/y$ on the left just makes unsolvable for $x$ by standard closed-form means, so far as I can tell. You can't factor it "in" to create an expression with roots or a solvable polynomial.

Comment: I understand we can't get a closed form equation for x. But z/y, a/m1, and b/m2 are all ratios such that, 0<(z/y)<1, 0<(a/m1)≤1, and 0<(b/m2)≤1, and {0<x≤1 if and a+b < m1 or m2} can this be useful in studying the equation can we derive something new from this information that can be helpful.